# Second UIWindow as dismiss tooltip

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a question. I need to use a second UIWindow on top of the current application window to present a toolTips. Tooltips will be presented and second window is disposed as soon as touched.

Does anybody get rejected an app because of creating a second UIWindow object in an iPhone application.

Thanks

Comment: Please review your questions and accept answers whenever applicable. From the Stack Overflow FAQ: ‘When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)’

Answer (score 1):

Creating a second window is perfectly acceptable. And there are apps in the store that do this currently. Reeder is one good example, where they place a window over top of the status bar to indicate things like downloading new content, caching images, etc.